# Help identify my bonsai tree

Tags: identification, trees, bonsai

I've been given a bonsai tree by a friend who knew I was interested in learning about them. Unfortunately all it said on the pack was 'bonsai tree'.

I've done a little research looking for the name of it, my best guess is a fukien tea tree but I'm not totally convinced on closer inspection.
[image: Wide view]
[image: Berries and leaves 1]
[image: Berries and leaves 2]

I got it with some berries already on it, in the dark purple, red and white / light green.

The leaves seem to be pointed oval with toothed edges in an alternating pattern on the branches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I want to try shaping and pruning it soon and would love to do it some justice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had it confirmed today that it is in fact a Sageretia Theenze (Chinese sweet plum, or Bird plum).

[image: Comparison image]

Some Identifying factors:

1. New leaf growth is a reddish brown which matures into the green colour
2. Back buds very easily, even from mature wood
3. Small white flowers give way to dark blue / purple Berry type fruits
4. Semi tropical (evergreen indoors, deciduous outdoors in temperate zones)

Incase it helps anyone in the future, a good care guide can be downloaded from [here](http://www.bonsaitoolchest.com/v/vspfiles/caresheets/chinese-sweet-plum.pdf)

Comment: Lucky you this time it was indeed a plum tree :s

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fruit, leaves, and what little detail I can get from the trunk and bark, I would have to say this is some sort of plum tree.

Maybe in the realm of a Stanley plum.

Comment: Just tried one of the 'berries' and it does indeed taste of some sort of plum. Is it possible to germinate these seeds?

Comment: @AvieRose I didn't tell you to eat it!!!

Comment: @AvieRose anyway, you can plant the stones after you stratify them. Wrap them in a paper towel, put in the bottom back of your fridge and forget them for 6 weeks. Then they may germinate.